# Pass checkbox values to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my function to get some data from a database table and put checkboxes a page.

```
function myfunction() {

  var dataObject = {};

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:45217/api/Symptom/LoadSymptom",
    type: "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {

      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + response[i].SymptomName + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + "<input type=checkbox  tr.id=" + i + " value=" + i + ">" + "</td>");

        $('table').append(tr);
      }
    }
  });

}
```

How I pass this checkbox values to server.

Comment: Check your code first - `tr.append("<td>" + "<input type=checkbox  id=" + i + " value=" + i + ">" + "</td>");`
It should be `id` not `tr.id`. That'll be an issue. Also can you please elaborate your ques?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( "YourServerPageToProcessData.php", function( dataToSendToServer ) { /* client action on success or error here */ });
```

-- have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an Ajax request each time user clicks on checkbox, you can do that in 2 ways-

Define function you want to perform onClick-

`function someFn() {
    // perform some Ajax request
}`

Method 1:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + response[i].SymptomName + "</td>");
    tr.append('<td><input type=checkbox  id="' + i + '" value=' + i + ' onclick="someFn()"></td>');

    $('table').append(tr);
  }
```

Method 2:

`$('input[id^="symptom_chkbox_"]').on('click', function(){
     // perform some Ajax request
})`

```
  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + response[i].SymptomName + "</td>");
    tr.append('<td><input type="checkbox" id="symptom_chkbox_' + i + '" value=' + i + '></td>');

    $('table').append(tr);
  }
```